# doctrine2 foreign key gets not created

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have two simple entities connected to each other with a OneToMany association.

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Shopware\CustomModels\JoeKaffeeAbo\Client")
* @ORM\Table(name="joe_kaffee_abo_client")
*/
class Client extends ModelEntity
{

public function __construct() {
    $this->abos = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Shopware\CustomModels\JoeKaffeeAbo\Abo", mappedBy="client", cascade= "all")
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
protected $abos;

public function addAbo($abo)
{
    //$this->abos[] = $abo;
    $this->abos->add($abo);
}
```

The second one is Abo:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Shopware\CustomModels\JoeKaffeeAbo\Abo")
* @ORM\Table(name="joe_kaffee_abo_abos")
*/
class Abo extends ModelEntity
{

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shopware\CustomModels\JoeKaffeeAbo\Client",inversedBy="abos")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="clientId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $client;
}
```

Somehow the join column gets not filled - it seems that doctrine ignores the association I set up. And if I call $client->addAbo($abo) there gets not relation created...and I cant receive the added abos via a getter function which returns the abo array collection.

Comment: Are you expecting a third table to be created?  Your title is confusing.  There is no need for an additional table with a OneToMany relation.

Comment: Your are right, there is no need for an additional table. I'm sorry for the title. I changed it. Anyway the problem was that the column with the foreignKey wasnt filled correctly. Meanwhile the problem is solved. But I don't know why. I just renamed the used tables. Deleted Cache und started everything again. I also have to mention that my doctrine framework instance is running within a webshop called "Shopware" maybee there's a bug...